# curiously recurring template pattern and infinite recursion

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, crtp

Take a look at the following simple curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) example:

```
template<class Derived>
struct base
{
    void foo() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();
    }
};

struct derived
    : public base<derived>
{};
```

Since `derived` has no member function `foo` other than the one derived from `base`, the invocation `derived{}.foo()` yields an infinite recursion. Can we modify the definition of `base::foo` such that `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo()` is only invoked when there is a `Derived::foo`?

**EDIT**: The reason why I'm asking is that the `foo` in my actual application has a template argument. And since a template method cannot be virtual, CRTP seems to be the only workaround.

Comment: So I can answer the question (you just need to define a function "foo" that hides the base "foo" - but doing such really implies you want simple inheritance not CRTP.

Comment: Just add an empty `foo()`  to your derives class. Problem solved. Otherwise, have a look at is_valid from [here](https://jguegant.github.io/blogs/tech/sfinae-introduction.html) or from boost::hana.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we modify the definition of `base::foo` such that `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo()` is only invoked when there is a `Derived::foo`?

One way to force a definition in `Derived::foo` is to overload the functions with a dummy argument.

```
template <typename Derived>
struct base
{
    void foo() {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo(0);   // Requires Derived::foo(int)
    }
};
```

or

```
template <typename Derived>
struct base
{
    void foo(int ) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();  // Requires Derived::foo(void)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to change the return type of `base::foo` to a dummy tag, we can check if calling `Derived::foo` returns the same tag or not and depending on that call the derived version.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Derived>
class base
{
    private:
    struct Tag {};

    public:
    Tag foo() {
        if constexpr (!std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<Derived>().foo()), Tag>) {
            static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();
        }

        return {};
    }
};

struct derived
    : public base<derived>
{};

struct derived2
    : public base<derived>
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo!"; }
};

int main() {
    derived d;
    derived2 d2;

    d.foo();
    d2.foo();
}
```

Comment: @AmiTavory You're right, my mistake. Found a new approach that works better.